# Replication and sharding combinations

Tags: replication, sharding, scalability

In modern relational databases, what combinations of replication and sharding are possible?

Actually, I'm interested in the following strategy. Is it possible to replicate a small table in order to avoid cross-shard joins whereas a large table is sharded? Like this:

- Node `1`

  - Table `orders_male`
  - Table `genders`
- Node `2`

  - Table `orders_female`
  - Table `genders`

Both `order_male` and `order_female` contain foreign key that references  the `genders` table.

Comment: This sounds like a 'do my research for me' question. Replication and shading are common and involve tradeoffs. Care to more narrowly define the question with less artificial example.

Comment: Since you have not specified a particular RDBMS, you may not get as many answers as you like.  The question is in an area where the differences could be significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Db2 for LUW DPF (Data Partitioning Feature) allows that transparently (see `CREATE TABLE ... DISTRIBUTE BY REPLICATION` [in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.partition.doc/doc/c0004126.html)). You can probably roll your own with other popular RDBMSes using a combination of federation/dblinks/linked servers, materialized views and/or engine-specific replication solutions.

So, to answer your questions:

> what combinations of replication and sharding are possible?

Too many to list here.

> is it possible to replicate a small table in order to avoid cross-shard joins?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting puzzle.

MySQL leaves most of the work to the user when it comes to sharding.

In your tiny example, `gender` should be identical on both shards, but the burden of maintaining such is left to the DBA.

`FOREIGN KEYs` are generally not viable in any `PARTITIONing` or sharding setup.  (Your simplified example will probably work.)

The typical shard+repl setup is each shard is composed of several servers.  Those servers are configured in some replication (M-S, Galera, Group Replication, etc) for HA and/or read scaling.

It is theoretically possible for `gender` to be on some master that is separate from all the shards.  I have not heard of such, but I don't see why it would not work.

Note.  You *may* need "multi-source" replication, which is a relatively new MySQL/MariaDB feature, especially if each shard is some form of multi-Master.  This *may* lead to a problem if the Master that is the 'slave' to the `gender` source dies.  I can't envision (off the top of my head) how to heal the replication topology without some messy manual effort.